# type.Assembly gives wrong assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection, com, .net-assembly

I want to create a reference to the Excel assembly and use this code:

```
[Test]
public void ExcelTest()
{
    Assembly current = this.GetType().Assembly;
    Assembly excel = typeof(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook).Assembly;
    Assert.AreEqual(current.FullName, excel.FullName); // Why is excel the same as current assembly?
}

[Test]
public void MscorlibTest()
{
    Assembly mscorlib = typeof(string).Assembly;
    Assert.IsTrue(mscorlib.FullName.StartsWith("mscorlib"));

    Assembly current = this.GetType().Assembly;
    Assert.AreNotEqual(mscorlib.FullName,current.FullName); // As expected
}
```

Why is excel the same as my current assembly?

What is a nice way to get the Excel assembly?

Could not find my dumb when reading [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel, among others, is reached via a COM interop type. It is an interface, decorated with GUID's and stuff. When you use it, it uses COM to communicate with a running Excel application. So your reference is not Excel itself, but merely a thin COM communication layer.

COM interop types may be embedded into your assembly, that seems to be the case here. You can specify that as a property of the assembly reference in your project.

See for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997297%28v=vs.110%29.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317478.aspx

Comment: +1 that would make sense, question is how do I get the Excel assembly given that?

Comment: @Johan Larsson As far as I know there is no Excel assembly. Excel is a native application, an assembly is a .NET library. That's why you have to use COM interop to use it with .NET.

Comment: @Dirk Assembly.LoadFile(path) gives the excel assembly but it feels so stringy.

Comment: I think Excel is written in C++. COM is a platform-independent communication layer. COM is a big deal in .NET because it can be used to communicate with non-.NET software. While Excel.exe is running, it is acting as a COM server, and your application is a COM client. When you add a reference to a COM interface, either a vendor-supplied interop assembly is used or a new one is generated from a type library. This COM interface layer is in a .NET assembly. But it is a communication layer only, it is useless without the native Excel itself.